# TypeScript unchecked index access

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript think an object in an array is possibly undefined when `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` configuration is enabled even after the length is checked?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIAeAXMiAK4YBG0uAvrrgCYQIA2cUKAbl8sEwBnMuggYA2gF0mwGAApB4oQDp2EEAHMwAC2QBeQ8gBMAShz5CCAPYghYZBJjAo9gDTIhbW8ykGBwkyEyM6uYCpElgReNiDMEQy4QA)

```js
interface Item {
    x: number
}

declare var items: Item[]

if(items.length === 2) { // Length is checked
    const [first, second] = items

    first.x // Error: Object is possibly undefined
    second.x // Error: Object is possibly undefined
}
```

I would expect the `length === 2` to "prove" to TypeScript that the object in the first and second position of the array are present.